# Android check when outgoing call is received by callee

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm developing on android framework,

I want to fire an event when an outgoing call is received by the callee , and also when the call is ended (from any of the two sides)

Comment: You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html for getting the event...

Comment: I checked the telephony API, the ringing state is only called when the phone is the caller, but in an outgoing call it's not any of the phone states (idle, offhook)

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to know wheter the calling party has recieved the call, you will need to create a listener.

```
class PhoneInfo extends BroadcastReceiver {
/**
 * Getting the System Telephony Service and registering a listener for Voice Call state
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    IncomingCallListener phoneListener = new IncomingCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

class IncomingCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        Log.i(logcat,"CALL_STATE changed " + callflag);

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.i(logcat,"CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                                    //This is where call ends.
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                                    //This is where we know call is established
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.i(logcat,"CALL_STATE_RINGING");
            break;
        }


    }

}
```

Register this with your activity as
`phoneInfo = new PhoneInfo(this);`
`registerReceiver(phoneInfo, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL));`

Now with Logs u can see how states are changed when a call is dialed or received.

Comment: Thanks for your code, Can I register the receiver with android manifest instead ??

Comment: Actually I just realized that this is the current solution I'm running, but the fact is every outgoing call creates a new listener and thus I may have 6 listeners after 6 outgoing calls, what do you think about it ???

Comment: Another thing is that no event happens when the calee answers the call, I think that phone state has nothing to do with what I want to do

Comment: Seems like a lot developers still can't read. He asked about a call that gets connected. Your solution is already posted all over stackoverflow and does not address the question. None of the states you have in your code indicates a connected call.