# Is it possible to know using TelephonyManager (onCallStateChanged) when the other person answers the call?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am developing an application that starts an alarm (**Ringtone**) when I start a call and it also set speaker mode on. So I would like to stop the alarm when the person who I am calling answers the call. How could I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
private PhoneStateListener phoneCallListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

    private int prevCallState=TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    if (prevCallState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){                         
                        //Inicio de llamada saliente                            
                        audiomanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                        audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

                    } 
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (prevCallState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                        //Fin de llamada saliente
                         audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                    }
                    break;                   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    prevCallState = state;
    }
};
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[Android check when outgoing call is received by callee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913267/android-check-when-outgoing-call-is-received-by-callee)

hey check this link may try this it can helpful to you to sort out your issue.#Ravindra

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, it is not possible to check if the person have picked up the phone nor his/her phone is not reachable. There is no feedback from the telephone companys in gsm networks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+9196203333"));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }

    });

}

//monitor phone call activities
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and also give permission in Manifest

Comment: I want to know exactly when the other person answers the phone but I think @tamasJozsa is right and there is no way to get that state